# Sloped tiles in Platformer

Tags: xna-4.0

I'm extreme new to game development and this is my second project. I’m working on a platform game that expands on the Platformer example provided at the app hub, so far I’ve got parallax scrolling (horizontal and vertical), moving platforms, tight touch controls, double jumps, melee attacks projectiles, and Game State management all working. BUT for the life of me I can’t figure out how to implement sloped tiles. I’ve searched for a ton of tutorials but I can’t find any good ones (by good I mean ones that i can understand). Again I would but grateful for any help that someone could provide.

Here is the code i am using for collisions (I've edit it to try and incorporate the code from the link below but still no luck. it runs but this code still treats the sloped tile as if they were regular tiles:

Edited Code

```cs
    /// <summary>
    /// Detects and resolves all collisions between the player and his neighboring
    /// tiles. When a collision is detected, the player is pushed away along one
    /// axis to prevent overlapping. There is some special logic for the Y axis to
    /// handle platforms which behave differently depending on direction of movement.
    /// </summary>


     private void HandleCollisions()
    {
        // Get the player's bounding rectangle and find neighboring tiles.
        Rectangle bounds = BoundingRectangle;
        int leftTile = (int)Math.Floor((float)bounds.Left / Tile.Width);
        int rightTile = (int)Math.Ceiling(((float)bounds.Right / Tile.Width)) - 1;
        int topTile = (int)Math.Floor((float)bounds.Top / Tile.Height);
        int bottomTile = (int)Math.Ceiling(((float)bounds.Bottom / Tile.Height)) - 1;

        // Was the player on a ramp last frame? 
         bool wasOnRamp = isOnRamp; 

        float dist =
            (float)Math.Sqrt
            (Math.Pow
            (MathHelper.Clamp
            (bounds.Center.X - bounds.Left, 0, Tile.Width), 2) +
            Math.Pow
            (MathHelper.Clamp
            (bounds.Bottom - bounds.Bottom, 0, Tile.Height), 2));

        float slopeTopLeft =
            (bounds.Bottom -
            ((bounds.Center.X - bounds.Left) *
            (float)Math.Sin
            (Math.Atan2
            (bounds.Height,
            (bounds.Center.X - bounds.Left)))));

        float slopeTopRight =
            (bounds.Bottom -
            ((bounds.Center.X - bounds.Right) *
            (float)Math.Sin
            (Math.Atan2
            (bounds.Height,
            (bounds.Center.X - bounds.Right))))); 

        // Reset flag to search for ground collision. 
        isOnGround = false;
        isOnRamp = false; 


        //For each potentially colliding movable tile.  
        foreach (var movableTile in level.movableTiles)
        {

            // Reset flag to search for movable tile collision.    
            movableTile.PlayerIsOn = false;

            //check to see if player is on tile.    
            if ((BoundingRectangle.Bottom >= movableTile.BoundingRectangle.Top) &&
                (BoundingRectangle.Left >= movableTile.BoundingRectangle.Left - (BoundingRectangle.Width)) &&
                (BoundingRectangle.Right <= movableTile.BoundingRectangle.Right + (BoundingRectangle.Width)))
            {
                if ((BoundingRectangle.Bottom < movableTile.BoundingRectangle.Top + 5))
                {

                    movableTile.PlayerIsOn = true;

                }

            }



            bounds = HandleCollision(bounds, movableTile.Collision, movableTile.BoundingRectangle);
        }


        //  for (int x = leftTile; x <= rightTile; ++x)
        // {
        //  TileCollision collision = Level.GetCollision(x, bottomTile);
        // if (collision == TileCollision.SlantedUp || collision == TileCollision.SlantedDown)
        // {
        //    isOnRamp = true;
        // }
        // } 



        // For each potentially colliding tile,
        for (int y = topTile; y <= bottomTile; ++y)
        {
            for (int x = leftTile; x <= rightTile; ++x)
            {
                // If this tile is collidable,
                TileCollision collision = Level.GetCollision(x, y);

                /*
                if (collision == TileCollision.SlantedUp)
                {
                    //create a rectangle collision box 
                    Rectangle tileCol = Level.GetBounds(x, y); //new Rectangle(x * Tile.Size, (y * Tile.Size), Tile.Size, Tile.Size + 1);



                    //if player collision "col" collides with "tileCol" and you haven't done this before this itteration (only happens once per full double loop) 
                    if (bounds.Intersects(tileCol) && !isOnRamp)
                    {

                        //get the angle of the tile 
                        float angle = level.angle;  // [level.tile[x, y]];

                        //get the x distance of how far away the player's right is inside the tile 
                        float dist = (bounds.X + bounds.Width) - tileCol.X;


                        //constructs the opposite of a right triangle 
                        float opposite = (float)(Math.Tan(MathHelper.ToRadians(angle)) * (dist));

                        if (angle < 90)
                        {
                            //if player's right is less then or equal to tile's right 
                            if (bounds.X + bounds.Width <= tileCol.X + tileCol.Width)
                            {
                                //place player on slope. this works properly 
                                position.Y = tileCol.Y - opposite;
                                //tell the program we don't wanna go through this again until the next full loop starts. 
                                isOnRamp = true;
                            }
                        }

                        else if (angle > 90)
                        {
                            if ((bounds.X + bounds.Width) >= tileCol.X)
                            {
                                //this is where the error is. the player goes "up" a slope that's 315 degrees, instead of down it. 
                                //how do I make the player go down the slope that's 315 degrees!? 
                                position.Y = tileCol.Y + opposite;
                                isOnRamp = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }

                */


                //If we touched a checkpoint tile, set our new checkpoint here
                if (collision == TileCollision.Checkpoint)
                    level.checkpoint = new Vector2(x, y) * Tile.Size;

                if (collision != TileCollision.Passable)
                {
                    float angleInRadians = MathHelper.ToRadians(45);
                    float m = (float)Math.Sin(angleInRadians) / (float)Math.Cos(angleInRadians);

                    // Determine collision depth (with direction) and magnitude.
                    Rectangle tileBounds = Level.GetBounds(x, y);
                    Vector2 depth = RectangleExtensions.GetIntersectionDepth(bounds, tileBounds);
                    if (depth != Vector2.Zero)
                    {
                        float absDepthX = Math.Abs(depth.X);
                        float absDepthY = Math.Abs(depth.Y);

                        // List<TileEdge> collidableEdges = Level.GetCollidableEdges(x, y);

                        // Resolve the collision along the shallow axis.
                        if (absDepthY < absDepthX || collision == TileCollision.Platform)
                        {
                            // If we crossed the top of a tile, we are on the ground.
                            if (previousBottom <= tileBounds.Top)
                                isOnGround = true;

                            // Ignore platforms, unless we are on the ground.
                            if (collision == TileCollision.Impassable || IsOnGround)
                            {
                                // Resolve the collision along the Y axis.
                                Position = new Vector2(Position.X, Position.Y + depth.Y);

                                // Perform further collisions with the new bounds.
                                bounds = BoundingRectangle;
                            }
                        }
                        else if (collision == TileCollision.Impassable) // Ignore platforms.
                        {
                            // Resolve the collision along the X axis.
                            Position = new Vector2(Position.X + depth.X, Position.Y);

                            // Perform further collisions with the new bounds.
                            bounds = BoundingRectangle;
                        }

                        else if (collision == TileCollision.SlantedUp)
                        {
                           // float dist = (bounds.X + bounds.Width) - depth.X;
                           // float opposite = (float)(Math.Tan(MathHelper.ToRadians(45)) * (dist));

                           //  float a = Position.X - bottomTile;

                            //bounds = m * a + absDepth.Y;

                           //  Position = new Vector2(Position.X + depth.X, Position.Y - opposite);

                           // bounds = BoundingRectangle;

                            // Resolve the collision along the Y axis.   
                            Position = new Vector2
                                (Position.X, slopeTopLeft);
                            Position = new Vector2
                                ((float)Math.Round(Position.X),
                                (float)Math.Round(Position.Y));

                            // Perform further collisions with the new bounds.   
                            bounds = BoundingRectangle;
                       }


                    }
                }
            }
        }



        // Save the new bounds bottom.
        previousBottom = bounds.Bottom;
    }

    private Rectangle HandleCollision(Rectangle bounds, TileCollision collision, Rectangle tileBounds)
    {
        Vector2 depth = RectangleExtensions.GetIntersectionDepth(bounds, tileBounds);
        if (depth != Vector2.Zero)
        {
            float absDepthX = Math.Abs(depth.X);
            float absDepthY = Math.Abs(depth.Y);


            // Resolve the collision along the shallow axis.  
            if (absDepthY < absDepthX || collision == TileCollision.Platform)
            {
                // If we crossed the top of a tile, we are on the ground.  
                if (previousBottom <= tileBounds.Top)
                    isOnGround = true;

                // Ignore platforms, unless we are on the ground.  
                if (collision == TileCollision.Impassable || IsOnGround)
                {
                    // Resolve the collision along the Y axis.  
                    Position = new Vector2(Position.X, Position.Y + depth.Y);

                    // Perform further collisions with the new bounds.  
                    bounds = BoundingRectangle;
                }
            }
            else if (collision == TileCollision.Impassable) // Ignore platforms.  
            {
                // Resolve the collision along the X axis.  
                Position = new Vector2(Position.X + depth.X, Position.Y);

                // Perform further collisions with the new bounds.  
                bounds = BoundingRectangle;
            }



        }
        return bounds;
    }
```

Comment: This question is pretty similar to the one here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/17922/how-to-make-a-platformer-character-go-down-a-315-degree-slope You may want to read my answer there.

Comment: hey thanks for that i actually saw that earlier in the day and I couldn't quite understand that post

I tried to use it but the I can't figure out how to implement it for example:

Does lv = level

Does col = tileBounds

Does pos = Position 

Does tileCol = Collision

ETC.

(sorry to be such a noob)

Answer (score 8):

Sorry codeless answer here, though hopefully you will find quite useful if you can bothered writing the simple code to accompany the technique.

This is a technique i use quite a bit in platformers to handle slopes. I call it the "5 Point Collision" technique.

[image: Yay for 2 second art :D]

Basically, your character has 5 main points associated with them, as shown in the image above.

2 head collision points (green)
2 wall collision points (red)
1 ground collision point (yellow)

Every step of the game you check collision on each of these 5 points when moving. If either of the head collision points are hit, you have jumped to high! If either of the wall collision points are hit, you have hit a wall, and if your ground collision point is hit, you have hit the ground, and should move your character up a pixel (until it no longer detects ground).

So how does this handle slopes?

Well if you look at the image above, you'll notice that some things may be low enough to pass under the wall collision points, and then hit the ground collision point, forcing the character to move upwards. This means if you had a slope, if the slope is too great, it will hit the wall collision point before the ground collision point; no access. However if the slope is low enough, it shall hit the ground collision point before the wall collision point, moving the character up, and therefore making the character walk up the slope.

Extra points can be added for collision detection to improve mechanics, though remember every point you add means more calculations...

Adding two ground collision points, and spreading them evenly along the bottom sometimes helps. The further the ground collision points are from the middle, the steeper slopes are that the player can handle. Alternatively you could just make the wall collision points higher up, but this may not end well (your character may end up "Jumping" onto obstacles. So my advice is keep the wall collisions reasonably low, (remember if the head collision points are in the corner as shown in my image, then they can also act as wall collision points).

Sorry don't have access to any code to help you out here, and its 1am, too tired to think of it off the top of my head.

Hope it helps you, and if not, someone else who glances by :)

Comment: This is a neat technique! I'd like to add that having 3 ground collision points (two at the sides) might be useful too. For instance, it could be used to detect when the player is on the edge of a platform (i.e. when only one of the side ground points collides), and play a different animation, for instance, like he's about to fall.

Comment: But I also find this is better for a pixel perfect environment. If the world is entirely tiled and without pixel perfect collisions, and the slopes have a fixed angle (as is usually the case), calculating it like annonymously mentioned will be easier and more efficient.

Comment: i made a pixel based game, each pixel was actually 4x4. The player was 8 pixels high and i put the wall collisions at 5 pixels high, meaning he could go up one pixel in height, but not 2. So this works well with non-sloped tiles (that give the effect of a slope), but yes, ananonymously's example is better for tiled slopes. Also, yes, the two extra corner tiles is a good idea. :D

Answer (score 5):

If you know what the angle of the tile is then you can just find the gradient of the slope:

```cs
// angle is the angle of the sloped tile
// m is the gradient = rise/run
// c is the offset up of the slope, you may want to make it negative as the computer
// screen coordinates are upside down.

float angleInRadians = MathHelper.ToRadians(angle);
float m = Math.Sin(angleInRadians)  // Sin gives us the height, and Cos gives us the width
       /  Math.Cos(angleInRadians); // It's best to only work this out once (like in LoadContent)

float x = playerX - tileX; // playerX is the x coordinate of the player
                           // tileX is the x coordinate of the tile's bottom left corner

// y = mx + c
playerY = m * x + tileY; // In this case, c will be the y coordinate of the bottom left corner of the sloped tile.
```

Comment: in your code is angle a float or a double

Comment: whatever is easier for you :) but if you use double you need to cast it to float in the method 'ToRadians'

Comment: Id also like to note that at certain angles (90 and 270) calculating m will give a divide by zero error because of the way that Sin and Cos work, so you can check for it if you want. Of course you probably wont use a sloped tile to go straight up and down, so it most likely won't happen

Comment: i have set angle as a double but i'm getting an error that says i can't implicitly convert a float to a double

Comment: make this line: float angleInRadians = MathHelper.ToRadians(angle); into: float angleInRadians = MathHelper.ToRadians((float)angle);

Comment: From what you've said I'd suggest getting a book on C# or perhaps do some tutorials to cover the basics of programming. It can be really useful and sometimes necessary later on.

Comment: ok i've the first part working had to do it like so:                   <!-- language: c# --> float angleInRadians = MathHelper.ToRadians(level.angle);
            float m = (float)Math.Sin(angleInRadians) / (float)Math.Cos(angleInRadians);

Comment: the problem now is everytime the player touches a sloped tile he's sent flying into the air

Comment: can you edit your question and add the exact code you're using to the post

Comment: I've updated the code now it paritially works but the player bounce up and down on the slopes and will run thru the entirely if he is moving too fast

Comment: You've run into a problem called tunneling. here is a question that has a useful answer for fixing a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235382/preventing-tunneling-with-this-setup